# jquery page resize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I'm just starting out with JQuery so I'm an utter noob, but I've been following the codecademy tutorial and am trying to implement a page resize function to fit into a resized browser. However nothing is working inside the script tags with jquery inside - even alerts aren't happening. The first script runs fine and says hi, but neither of the other two alerts work, nor any of the Jquery stuff. I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but there are two soundcloud widgets on the page as well, one which is a programmable widget.

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("Hi");</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hello");
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Jquery");
        $(window).resize(function() {   
            if ($(window).width() < 1020) {
                $('#page').css("width", "500px");
            }
        )};                 
}); 
</script>
```

Apart from figuring out why nothing happens, I'd also like to know if this resize thing works.

Comment: check your console for error. Be aware, you don't need to wrap window handler inside document ready handler

Comment: If you don't know if widgets make a difference - get rid of them temporarily to check it.

Comment: Note that what you are trying to do can easily be done with media queries.

Comment: Thanks A. Wolff, I will definitely check my console in Chrome in future, didn't realise that listed JS errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got syntax error : window.resize should close with `});` not `)};`

And be sure you called jQuery first.

By the way : why don't you simply use Media Queries ?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
 #page {
   width: 500px;

 }
}
```

Comment: A real pleasure to correct your syntax errors and get -1 vote :)

Comment: There is a serial downvoter here ;) And ya, this is a syntax error so this for sure doesn't deserve a downvote

Comment: Ahh, didn't know some guys have time to spent to downvote for fun, I will remember, thank you.

Comment: @enguerranws LOL :D :D

Comment: @enguerranws some guys use it to make their answer appears first then remove downvote to not lose points, old sh!tty trick still in use. {not sure this has something to do here but who knows...?}

Comment: I shall definitely look up media queries, but I was thinking originally of resizing using ($(window).width() - 50 + 'px') instead of 500px. what's the benefit of media queries over that?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the head section of your page, it sounds like you do not have the jquery library loaded.  You must include a reference to the library, you can download it to your server of reference it by including `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` on your page (before any calls to $)

Answer (score 1):

If your script isn't doing anything, almost certainly you have a syntax error somewhere within your `<script>` tag that is causing the code to be invalid and fail to run.

In this situation, your problem is that you haven't closed your resize call / function parameter properly:

```
    $(window).resize(function() {   
        if ($(window).width() < 1020) {
            $('#page').css("width", "500px");
        }
    )};
```

should be

```
    $(window).resize(function() {   
        if ($(window).width() < 1020) {
            $('#page').css("width", "500px");
        }
    });
```

Note that the parentheses and curly braces at the end of the function must be closed in exactly the opposite order as they were opened at the start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have included the jquery library

****try this code:****

```
<script>
    $(function () {

                var oldY = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                if (oldY <= 1020) {
                    $('#page').css({'width', '500px'});          
                 }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Why mix plain JS and jQuery in this case, when jQuery can do it all?

Comment: And where is the resize handler?

Comment: this code is working... passing the value of client width to a variable and then check it

Comment: That will do the job on document load, not on resize.

Answer (score 0):

First correct the syntax by changing `)}` into `})`. Than make sure you are including the jquery.js file before using jQuery code. Something like:

```
<html><head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>//jQuery Code here</script>
</head>
<body>
     <script>//jQuery Code here</script>
</body></html>
```

Maybe open the console and check the javascript error messages (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> in Chrome/Firefox others might be different). Also enter `$ === jQuery` into the console and see to which it is evaluated (should be true if jQuery is bound to $).

It is a common shortcut in jQuery to use `$( function() { ... } ));` for document.ready see [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

If you are using other JavaScript libs that might overwrite the $ use

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

to ensure $ is bound to jQuery.